# Save Page As XML

Tags: php, xml, imdb

I have made a script that generates an IMDB API link for a movie in XML.

Once this link is generated it will save to an XML file with its contents. The only issue is that the contents aren't saving.

Link generated:
http://imdbapi.org/?title=One+Piece&type=xml&plot=simple&mt=none&episode=0&aka=simple&release=simple

PHP script:

```
   $url="http://imdbapi.org/?title=One+Piece&type=xml&plot=simple&mt=none&episode=0&aka=simple&release=simple";

    $curl = curl_init();
    $data = fopen("text.xml", "w");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_exec ($curl);

    if ( !$data ) {
    echo "No";
} else {
    $contents = curl_exec($curl);
    fwrite($data, $contents);
}

curl_close($curl);
fclose($data);
```

Comment: Generally this works, however you might want to [increase the error reporting so PHP tells you about notices, warnings and errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504459/367456).

Comment: Yet another silly typo question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using file_get_contents, you can use CURL

```
$ch = curl_init('http://imdbapi.org/?title=One+Piece&type=xml&plot=simple&mt=none&episode=0&aka=simple&release=simple');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now $response shall contains your XML. And you can do something like

```
file_put_contents('filename.xml', $response);
```

make sure that filename.xml is writable

Comment: But that's not what's asked about.

Comment: I have updated the original response. The issue now is that it will write to a text file but not an xml

Comment: Hi, XML file is actually a text file with different extension. I'm not sure with this, can you please explain more?