# Get file from a URL using GET request?

Tags: php

I have to make a get request to a url to download a xml file hourly.  I am changing my code over to php.

in the past the code was :

```
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")


oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://api.sportsdatallc.org/golf-t1/leaderboard/pga/2012/tournaments/" & currentidString & "/leaderboard.xml?api_key="given key id", False
oXMLHTTP.Send

If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write oXMLHTTP.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "file.xml", 2
    oStream.Close
End If
```

how can I do this using php?  I am confused because of all the extra lines for http.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save Page As XML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15308344/342740)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("http://api.sportsdatallc.org/golf-t1/leaderboard/pga/2012/tournaments/" & currentidString & "/leaderboard.xml?api_key="given key id");
```

or you can use the curl library for more advanced requests

> http://www.php.net/curl

I hope this help.